# Unable to refer form in another form's procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

How do I refer a form when writing a procedure that is related to another form?
When I try to refer a form(not the current form) it returns null.in the image, the highlighted script in the project database window is where the code is written in.The form `Forms("All Patient Info")` is Null.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAJd7.png)

Comment: A _Form_ cannot be "Null", it is either open or not. So something else is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working. But the userform you are refering to must be opened, otherwise it won't be found. So add some routine like this:

```
If Not CurrentProject.AllForms("All Patient Info").IsLoaded Then

    DoCmd.OpenForm "All Patient Info", acNormal
End If
Forms("All Patient Info").txtTest.Caption = "LEL"
```

If you don't want the form to be visible while you are doing something, add

```
Application.Echo False
```

before you open the form. When you are done modifying the form, close it with

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, "All Patient Info"
```

And Enable Echo again:

```
Application.Echo True
```